Why is jquery.css() function to set an element's background-image url is not working?
I've been trying to apply background image to a div via the jquery.css() function, such as:
$('#div').css('backgrounds-image','./assets/imgs/flag.png');

Expected: to see the image being displayed on the div., but it didn't work.
HTML:
<div class="img-viewer"></div>

CSS:
div.img-viewer {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

JQuery:
$('div.img-viewer').css('background-image','./assets/imgs/flag.png');


"didn't work" how? What did it do instead? Also, did you use backgrounds-image or background-image? Only the latter is correct

Perhaps the image path isn't correct. Use your browser's dev-tools Console and Network panels to check the URL it's trying to use and see what the response is

I used background-image, and also I've checked the paths, the path loaded correctly if I use it with img.src. I just don't know why its not showing, and also if I put d same url in the css file, it works fine

What do you see in your browser devtools? What CSS is applied and what is not?

Oh, I realized that I didn't put my url string inside the css url() function as value to the background image. All thanks its works well now.

As per the documentation of: background-image
You are missing url() in your code. [syntax usage issue]
Here is a working example:


$('div.img-viewer').css('background-image', 'https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/half-alive-dead-tree-260nw-1718611903.jpg');
$('div.img-viewer-second').css('background-image', 'url(https://www.shutterstock.com/image-photo/half-alive-dead-tree-260nw-1718611903.jpg)');
div.img-viewer,
div.img-viewer-second {
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  background-image: none;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.img-viewer p {
  color: red;
}

div.img-viewer-second p {
  color: white;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="img-viewer">
  <p>First one without background image due to CSS syntax violation</p>
</div>
<br>
<div class="img-viewer-second">
  <p>Second one with background image due to correct CSS syntax usage</p>
</div>



